# SQL - Insert conditioned values in a View

Tags: sql, create-view

Let's suppose I created this table:

```
CREATE TABLE T (
  NAME VARCHAR(10),
  A INT NOT NULL,
  B INT NOT NULL
)
```

I want to create a view that has two attributes, T.Name and a char that is `'Y' if A >= B or 'N' otherwise`.
How can I build this second attribute? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `case` statement:

```
create view v as
    select t.name, (case when t.a >= t.b then 'Y' else 'N' end) as attribute
    from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE VIEW YourViewName
AS
SELECT name , (CASE WHEN A >= B THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) as your_name
FROM T
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build it with a case-when!